# Getting error The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement has been terminated

Tags: sql, .net

this is my  code

```
sqlcommand=new sqlcommand("inset into table values('"+home.name'"+,'"+home.DOJ'")",con);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the local default string conversion from `DateTime` (I assume) to string, and then hoping that's valid for SQL.

Additionally, your code has a [SQL injection attack vulnerability](http://bobby-tables.com).

Both of these can be fixed - and your code readability - can be improved using parameterized SQL:

```
using (var command = new SqlCommand(
    "INSERT INTO Foo (Name, DOJ) Values (@Name, @DOJ)", connection))
{
    command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = home.name;
    command.Parameters.Add("@DOJ", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = home.DOJ;
    ...
}
```

(Adjust the types accordingly, e.g. using `SqlDbType.NVarChar` and `SqlDbType.DateTime2`.)

*Never* put values directly into SQL like you were doing. Using parameterized SQL is a win all round.